# Fragment Error when using Firebase for Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-fragments

I am creating a bottom navigation for my android app. I am having the user login using Firebase and going into the first screen(home fragment). This fragment reads a JSON file and displays information which works fine.

The problem: 
When you click to switch to the Profile Fragment the app crashes and gives a Fatal error and I do not know how to fix this. I am relatively new to Android and I have tried many different "solution" with no success. Below are my fragments and main activity.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        loadFragment(new HomeFragment());

        //getting bottom navigation view and attaching the listener
        BottomNavigationView navigation = findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }
    private boolean loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        //switching fragment
        if (fragment != null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
                    .commit();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        Fragment fragment = null;

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.navigation_home:
                fragment = new HomeFragment();
                break;

            case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
                fragment = new DashboardFragment();
                break;

            case R.id.navigation_profile:
                fragment = new ProfileFragment();
                break;
        }
        return loadFragment(fragment);
    }
}
```

HomeFragment.java

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    List<Articles> articles;
    View rootView;
    private static String JSON_URL = "https://www.britbound.com/json/articles.json";
    Adapter adapter;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        recyclerView = rootView.findViewById((R.id.recView_articles));
        articles = new ArrayList<>();
        extractArticles();
        return rootView;
    }
    private void extractArticles(){
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(
                Request.Method.GET,
                JSON_URL,
                null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try{
                            JSONArray array = response.getJSONArray("articles");
                            for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++){
                                Articles article = new Articles();
                                JSONObject articleObj = array.getJSONObject(i);
                                article.setTitle(articleObj.getString("title").toString());
                                article.setPublishDate("Published: "+articleObj.getString("date_published").toString());
                                article.setExcerpt(articleObj.getString("excerpt").toString());
                                article.setThumbnail(articleObj.getString("thumbnail").toString());
                                articles.add(article);
                            }
                        }catch (JSONException e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

                        adapter = new Adapter(getContext(), articles);
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error){
                        // Do something when error occurred
                        Log.d("tag", "onErrorResponse: " + error.getMessage());
                    }
                }
        );

        // Add JsonObjectRequest to the RequestQueue
        queue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    }
}
```

ProfileFragment.java

```
public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment {
    TextView fullname, email,phone, verifyMsg;
    FirebaseAuth fAuth;
    FirebaseFirestore fStore;
    String userId;
    Button resendCode;
    View rootView;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);
        phone = rootView.findViewById(R.id.txt_userphonenumber);
        fullname = rootView.findViewById(R.id.txt_userfullname);
        email    = rootView.findViewById(R.id.txt_useremail);
        verifyMsg = rootView.findViewById(R.id.txt_emailnotverified);
        fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        fStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        resendCode = rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_verifyemail);
        userId = fAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

        final FirebaseUser user = fAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if(!user.isEmailVerified()){
            resendCode.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            verifyMsg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            resendCode.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    user.sendEmailVerification().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Verification email has been sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        private static final String TAG = "";

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: Email not sent " + e.getMessage());
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
        DocumentReference documentReference = fStore.collection("users").document(userId);
        ListenerRegistration registration =  documentReference.addSnapshotListener(getActivity(), new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                phone.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("phone"));
                fullname.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("fullname"));
                email.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("email"));
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }

}
```

ERROR

```
    --------- beginning of crash
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.britbound.britboundsocial, PID: 6457
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: FragmentManager is already executing transactions
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.ensureExecReady(FragmentManager.java:1776)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1841)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:489)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.ActivityScope.lambda$onFragmentActivityStopCallOnce$1(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.0:180)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.ActivityScope$$Lambda$2.run(Unknown Source:4)
        at android.app.Activity.runOnUiThread(Activity.java:6282)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.ActivityScope.onFragmentActivityStopCallOnce(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.0:164)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.ActivityScope.bind(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.0:192)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference.addSnapshotListenerInternal(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.0:514)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference.addSnapshotListener(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.0:456)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference.addSnapshotListener(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.0:397)
        at com.britbound.britboundsocial.fragments.ProfileFragment.onCreateView(ProfileFragment.java:74)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2698)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:310)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1185)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1354)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1432)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1495)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:447)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2167)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1990)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1945)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1847)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$4.run(FragmentManager.java:413)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
I
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!